# Spring 4 does not import EhCache

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea, ehcache

While migrating a project from Spring 3 to Spring 4 (using IntelliJ and Maven), I encountered a problem with this imported EhCache package:

> Error:(13,40) java: error: package org.springframework.cache.ehcache does not exist

Analyzing the problem, I found that Spring 3 was importing the ehCache package from `spring-context-support` which is included with maven's `spring-core` dependency.

Spring 4's `spring-core` does not include the `spring-context-support` which contains the ehcache package, so I manually added to the POM the dependency for `spring-context-support` as such:

**pom.xml**

```
  <spring.version>4.3.25.RELEASE</spring.version>
  <ehcache.version>2.5.0</ehcache.version>

  (...)

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  (...)

  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
    <version>${ehcache.version}</version>
  </dependency>
```

However, the dependency is not being imported at all. Only the `spring-context` lib gets imported which does not contain the ehCache package:

**Spring 3:**

[image]

**Spring 4**

[image]

Things I've tried:

- mvn clean install
- using IntelliJ to re-import maven dependencies
- deleting .idea folder and restarting IntelliJ to force dependency imports
- deleting the .m2 folder

What am I doing wrong here? How do I use EhCache with spring 4 and maven?

Answer (score 0):

I think for `ehcache` the dependency should be

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

when you check [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache-core), it indicates that the artifact has been moved to the one mentioned above.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've tried your sugestion, but unfortunately it still doesn't work

Comment: `org.ehcache` version 3.8.1, just as in your example

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that you Maven setup is not correct.

Could you run `mvn dependencies:tree` in the project where you added `spring-context-support` version `4.3.25`?

That will tell you whether or not Maven sees that dependency.
If it does not, I would check which file you edited vs. which project you are testing.